# insert statement not working and no error

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, insert

```
var lid = $('#lid').val();
$.ajax({
        type:"post",
        url:'../library/lib.php',
        data:'action=save_memo&lid'+lid,

        success:function(response){
            console.log(response);

        }
```

here is the content of lib.php

```
switch($action){
    case 'save_memo':
        save_memo($_POST['lid']);
        break;}

function save_memo($lid){
    $insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_memo (id) VALUES ('$lid')";

    if(mysql_query($insert) == false){
        $result = array("failed" => $insert)
    }else{
       $result = array("sucess" => $insert);
       echo json_encode($result);
    }
```

the response is success but it doesnt insert into the database
  please someone tell me what's wrong, thanks in advance

Comment: Replace $_POST['lid'] with $_POST['action'] in your PHP code and see if that works.

Comment: sorry, i have these before the switch $action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : '';

Comment: You should update your question with all the code that you have then.

Comment: `save_memo($_POST['lid']);` that should get a GET, since you're using `action=save_memo&lid` same for `type:"post",`

Comment: I doubt `../library/lib.php` in url work. `..` are for paths i suppose. try giving absolute/relative url like `http://your-site/library/lib.php` or `library/lib.php`

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.
 Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

Comment: still not working :|

Comment: i put begin(), commit() and rollback() and it worked. thanks for the help

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're missing an `=` sign in your jQuery call:

`data:'action=save_memo&lid'+lid`

Should be:

`data:'action=save_memo&lid='+lid,`

Also, check out the big red warning on the [mysql_query manual page](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php):

> Warning
>
> This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>
> - mysqli_query()
> - PDO::query()

Comment: `data:'action=save_memo&lid'+lid` and `data:'action=save_memo&lid='+lid,` Plus, OP has `data:'action=save_memo&lid'+lid,` so the equal sign is in there.

Comment: Yes, the second one has an `=` sign at the end, which I'm pretty sure is not optional

Comment: lol silly me, sorry. Lordie, good thing it wasn't "bear season" around here!

Comment: But I'm also wondering, shouldn't the OP be using a GET method? Since they're using `save_memo($_POST['lid']);` and their action? Doesn't seem to be right; not for me but I could be wrong though.

Comment: Semantically it should be POST (since it's inserting and 'changing something on the server'), I don't think there should be an issue there since their jQuery call is specifying `post`

Comment: I tried data:'action=save_memo', then tried to put values here $insert = "INSERT INTO tbl_memo (id) VALUES ('123')"; and still not working

Answer (score 0):

1. Your are posting the variable `action` with content `save_memo+[lid]`.  So when you attempt to retrieve `$_POST['lid']`, you will get `save_memo` concatenated with whatever the value of `#lid` is.
2. You do not retrieve the variable `$action` before attempting to evaluate it with the switch statement.
3. `$lid` is not a variable that was posted with the AJAX request, `$action` was.